# Accessing private data of a class obj

Tags: c++

Here goes the code where the function `operator+` overloading is accessing the private members of a class using `.` operator .Is that valid?Actually my problem is with the use of `.` operator .Can they be used to access private member directly?

```
   #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Box
{
   public:

      double getVolume(void)
      {
         return length * breadth * height;
      }
        void setLength( double len )
      {
          length = len;
      }

      void setBreadth( double bre )
      {
           breadth = bre;
      }

      void setHeight( double hei )
      {
      height = hei;
      }
                        // Overload + operator to add two Box objects.
  Box operator+(const Box& b)
      {
         Box box;
         box.length = this->length + b.length;     //These are my problem
         box.breadth = this->breadth + b.breadth;  //These are my problem
         box.height = this->height + b.height;     //These are my problem
         return box;
      }
   private:
      double length;      // Length of a box
      double breadth;     // Breadth of a box
      double height;      // Height of a box
};
// Main function for the program
int main( )
{
   Box Box1;                // Declare Box1 of type Box
   Box Box2;                // Declare Box2 of type Box
   Box Box3;                // Declare Box3 of type Box
   double volume = 0.0;     // Store the volume of a box here

   // box 1 specification
   Box1.setLength(6.0); 
   Box1.setBreadth(7.0); 
   Box1.setHeight(5.0);

   // box 2 specification
   Box2.setLength(12.0); 
   Box2.setBreadth(13.0); 
   Box2.setHeight(10.0);

   // volume of box 1
   volume = Box1.getVolume();
   cout << "Volume of Box1 : " << volume <<endl;

   // volume of box 2
    volume = Box2.getVolume();
    cout << "Volume of Box2 : " << volume <<endl;

   // Add two object as follows:
   Box3 = Box1 + Box2;

   // volume of box 3
   volume = Box3.getVolume();
   cout << "Volume of Box3 : " << volume <<endl;

   return 0;
    }
```

I don't understand how the function operator overloading can use the `.` operator for accessing private member .I learned that only the member function have access to private members of a class.They are not directly accessible ,than how can that function access it?Thank u.

Comment: Because `b` is also a `Box` (or a derivation of said-same). Said member function (operator +`) has access to the *class*, not just the current instance (this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are of the same type, they are natural `friends`.

C++ allows a `friend` to access `private` methods and properties of another class.

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/) for some more information.

Comment: box.length = this->length + b.length;     
box.breadth = this->breadth + b.breadth;  
box.height = this->height + b.height;                                    they should be accessed using member function ..I couldn't get u?

Comment: @Maizere private properties do not apply to `friend` objects.

Comment: But the operator+ is not a frind function ,than how can it access the private member directly?